# Que metodo de guardado me recomendarian para un formularios con varios productos?

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax, json, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber que método de guardado puedo utilizar para un formulario de pedidos ya que manejo varios input dinámicos para agregar varios productos, lo que quiero es que todo se pueda guardar en una sola fila para que tenga un id único con el que pueda llamar el pedido[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es para nada una buena idea hacer lo que piensas. Si te piden algo tan simple como saber cuántos productos hay en un pedido, ya te veo recurriendo a trucos horribles para seguir manteniendo un diseño pésimo. Cada producto debe tener su fila y su ID de pedido. Otro ejemplo que haria infumable tu diseño de datos: saber la cantidad de veces que un producto se vendió en un año, o entre dos fechas ... ¿cómo sacas eso con un diseño donde metiste en la misma fila todos los productos de un pedido?

Comment: @A. Cedano
 Es que los productos van a ser ingresado manualmente, si me fueran proporcionado los productos pero no lo hicieron, en ese caso creo que me tocaria crear formulario para registrar todos los productos y asi queden con su id y poder hacer esto de una manera ordenada, si tuvieran un id seria mas facil, pues asi lo relacionaria con otra tabla, pense lo mismo que tu pero por eso llegue a consultar si habia una manera pero veo que es absurdo hacer algo asi

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *ingresados manualmente*? Realmento, todo se hace *manualmente* sea el método que sea: formulario, archivo, llamada telefónica... alguien tiene que suministrar los datos y tú como programador los acoplas según tu modelo de datos. Supongamos incluso que hay un formulario mal hecho, pero eres tú el que recibes los datos de ese formulario mal hecho... pues tú puedes limpiar los datos al recibirlos y hacer que éstos se inserten según tus normas, que son las buenas, no según las normas de quien hizo el formulario y no tenía ni idea de un modelo de datos bien diseñado.